# Index view not passing parameter Id to mvc controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working with asp.net core MVC project and I have an issue when trying to get by Id API of my model from view (cshtml). (Please note the getbyid API works when testing with Postman)

My Model:

```
public class Movie
{

[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }

public string Title { get; set; }

public string Director { get; set; }

public DateTime DateReleased { get; set; }

[Range(0, 9)]
public int Rating { get; set; }

public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

My controller methods:

```
namespace MovieTheatreManagement.Controllers
{

[Route("api/Movie")]
[ApiController]
public class MovieController : Controller
{
    
    #region Fields

    private readonly IMovieRepository _movieRepository;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    #endregion Fields


    #region Constructors

    public MovieController(IMovieRepository movieRepository, IMapper mapper, ILogger<MovieController> logger)
    {
        _movieRepository = movieRepository;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    #endregion Constructors
    
    #region HtmlRequests
    
    [HttpGet("/")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_movieRepository.GetAllMovies().ToList().OrderBy(m => m.Id));
    }
    
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
    
    [HttpGet("Delete")]
    [Route("Delete/{id}")]
    public ActionResult Delete([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        var movie = _movieRepository.GetMovieById(id);
        return View(movie);
    }
    
    #endregion HtmlRequests

    [HttpGet("/All")]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<GetModels>> GetAllMovies()
    {
        var movieItems = _movieRepository.GetAllMovies();
        // var newitems = Convert.FromBase64String();
    
        return Ok(_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<GetModels>>(movieItems));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([FromForm]CreateModels movieRequest)
    {
        //CreateModels movieRequest = new CreateModels();
        _logger.LogInformation("hi I am create method");
        var movie = _mapper.Map<Movie>(movieRequest);
        _movieRepository.Create(movie);
        _movieRepository.SaveChanges();
        var command = _mapper.Map<GetModels>(movie);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
            //CreatedAtRoute(nameof(GetMovieById), new {Id = command.Id}, command);
    }

[HttpPost("id")]
public ActionResult ApplyDelete([FromRoute(Name = "id")]int id)
{
    var command = _movieRepository.GetMovieById(id);
    if (command == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    _movieRepository.DeleteMovie(command);
    _movieRepository.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

My Repository (Here is the issue where after I debug I am getting the id null)

```
public Movie GetMovieById(int id)
{
    return _context.Movies.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Id == id);
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<MovieTheatreManagement.Models.Movie>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Movie Theatre Management</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New Movie", "Create", "Movie", new{}, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
</p>
<p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div>
            @Html.TextBox("txtTitle", "")
            <input type="submit" value="Filter by Title" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    }
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateReleased)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Director)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rating)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Image)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateReleased)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Director)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rating)
            </td>
            <td>
                <img width="100px" height="100px" src=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Image) /> 
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |

                @Html.ActionLink("Delete Movie", "Delete", "Movie" ,new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Delete page:

```
@model MovieTheatreManagement.Models.Movie

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
}

<h2>Delete</h2>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
<div>
    <h4>Movie</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateReleased)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DateReleased)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Director)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Director)
        </dd>
        
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rating)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Rating)
        </dd>
        
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Image)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Image)
        </dd>

    </dl>

    @using (Html.BeginForm(actionName:"ApplyDelete", controllerName:"Movie", new { id = Model.Id } , FormMethod.Post)) {

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** I think the routeValues in my ActionLink is not getting me the ID that I need

Comment: What API is not working?

Comment: The Delete API as I am unable to get the ID, it is always coming as null after debugging.

Comment: What action are you calling? you have 2 deletes and both have id.

Comment: And could you please post your controller too?

Comment: Regarding the first question, I have 2 deletes because when the user clicks the delete link in my index page I want to forward to my delete page (which I forgot to mention but I will include in the edit). Second question, Sure I will post my controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActionLink is always calling GET metod

So fix  your action

```
[Route("Delete/{id}")]
public ActionResult Delete( int id)
.....
```

the same for others similar APIs

```
[Route("ApplyDelete/{id}")]
public ActionResult ApplyDelete(int id)
....
```

Comment: Ooof, the Route template did the work! Thank you so much Sergey.